# Output is always zeros (quotient and remainder) in divider code VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Output is always zeros (quotient and remainder) in the code shown below. 
Even if I assign value of b to remainder,it is giving 0. I have checked for many times but I am not able to understand what the issue is. While compiling, it is showing 2 warnings:

```
- Initial value of "b" depends on value of signal "divisor".
```

What is the problem?

-- DIVIDER

```
library ieee;  
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;  

entity unsigned_divider is  
port(
-- the two inputs  
dividend: in bit_vector(15 downto 0);  
divisor : in bit_vector(15 downto 0);  
-- the two outputs  
quotient : out bit_vector(15 downto 0);  
remainder : out bit_vector(15 downto 0)  
);  
end entity unsigned_divider;  

architecture behave of unsigned_divider is  

begin  
process  

variable a : bit_vector(15 downto 0):=dividend;  
variable b : bit_vector(15 downto 0):=divisor;  

variable p : bit_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');  
variable i : integer:=0;  
begin  

for i in 0 to 15 loop  
p(15 downto 1) := p(14 downto 0);  
p(0) := a(15);  
a(15 downto 1) := a(14 downto 0);  
p := bit_vector(unsigned(p) -  unsigned(b));  

if(p(15) ='1') then  
a(0) :='0';  
p := bit_vector(unsigned(p) +  unsigned(b));  
else  
a(0) :='1';  
end if;  
wait for 1 ns;  

end loop;

quotient <= a after 1 ns;  
remainder <= p  after 1 ns;  

end process;
end behave;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have explicit assignments to the variables a and b inside the process statement part (as sequential signal assignments). The declarations:

```
        variable a : bit_vector(15 downto 0):=dividend;  
        variable b : bit_vector(15 downto 0):=divisor;
```

Should be:

```
        variable a : bit_vector(15 downto 0);  
        variable b : bit_vector(15 downto 0);
```

And in the process statement part (following the begin in the process):

```
        a := dividend;
        b := divisor;
```

These overcome the issue natipar mentions, that the values are only assigned to a and b during initialization.

Further should you desire to have a 1 ns delay you should have an explicit wait statement as the last sequential statement of the process statement process statement part:

```
wait on dividend, divisor;
```

These make your process statement look something like this (with indentation added):

```
    process  

        variable a : bit_vector(15 downto 0); -- := dividend;  
        variable b : bit_vector(15 downto 0); -- := divisor;  

        variable p : bit_vector(15 downto 0) :=  (others => '0');  
        variable i : integer := 0;  
    begin  

        a := dividend;
        b := divisor;

        for i in 0 to 15 loop  
            p(15 downto 1) := p(14 downto 0);  
            p(0) := a(15);  
            a(15 downto 1) := a(14 downto 0);  
            p := bit_vector(unsigned(p) -  unsigned(b));  

            if  p(15)  = '1'  then  
                a(0) :='0';  
                p := bit_vector(unsigned(p) +  unsigned(b));  
            else  
                a(0) := '1';
            end if;  
            wait for 1 ns;  

        end loop;

        quotient <= a after 1 ns;  
        remainder <= p  after 1 ns;  

        wait on dividend, divisor;

    end process;
```

(Note the space between the numeric literal and the units, required by IEEE Std 1076-2008, 15.3 Lexical elements, separators and delimiters paragraph 4, the last sentence "At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal.", despite Modelsim not requiring it).

Writing a simple testbench we find at least one error in your restoring division algorithm:

```
entity unsigned_divider_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of unsigned_divider_tb is
    signal dividend, divisor: bit_vector (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal quotient, remainder: bit_vector (15 downto 0);

    function to_string(inp: bit_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  bit_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(BIT'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end;

begin
DUT:
    entity work.unsigned_divider
        port map (
            dividend,
            divisor,
            quotient,
            remainder
        );
MONITOR:
    process (quotient, remainder)
    begin
        report "quotient = " & to_string (quotient) severity NOTE;
        report "remainder = " & to_string (remainder) severity NOTE;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

> ghdl -a unsigned_divider.vhdl
>   ghdl -e unsigned_divider_tb
>   ghdl -r unsigned_divider_tb
>   unsigned_divider.vhdl:83:9:@0ms:(report note): quotient = 0000000000000000
>   unsigned_divider.vhdl:84:9:@0ms:(report note): remainder = 0000000000000000
>   unsigned_divider.vhdl:83:9:@17ns:(report note): quotient = 1111111111111111
>   unsigned_divider.vhdl:84:9:@17ns:(report note): remainder = 0000000000000000

(And a note on interpretation, the transactions reported at time 0 ms are the default assignments performed as a result of elaboration).

Your algorithm gives a wrong answer for division by 0.

Adding a stimulus process to the testbench:

```
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        dividend <= x"ffff";
        divisor <= x"000f";
    end process;
```

Shows it can get the right answer too:

> unsigned_divider.vhdl:83:9:@37ns:(report note): quotient = 0001000100010001
>   unsigned_divider.vhdl:84:9:@37ns:(report note): remainder = 0000000000000000

And with the testbench and added wait statements and assignments in the stimulus process you can explore further.

I've always been a fan of non-restoring division myself, because the adds or subtracts take a clock in a clocked divider.

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignments take effect immediately; but the signal, at the moment of the creation of that variable, has no value, so you cannot expect the assignments

```
variable a : bit_vector(15 downto 0):=dividend;  
variable b : bit_vector(15 downto 0):=divisor;
```

to work correctly. I'm a bit surprised that there are no complaints for the assignment to the variable `a` though. Perhaps it is your second warning. You should define the variables the way you do, but leave the assignment for later, in the `begin` segment of your process.

P.S. Also, you might want to change `remainder <= p  after 1ns;` to `remainder <= p  after 1 ns;`.

Comment: **And don't forget to define the signals that trigger your process!** "If a process sensitivity list appears following the reserved word process in a process statement, then the process statement shall not contain an explicit wait statement."  IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement, paragraph 8, first sentence. "In this document, the word shall is used to indicate a mandatory requirement.",  1.3 Structure and terminology of this document, 1.3.1 General, paragraph 4, first sentence.  A process containing an explicit wait statement won't contain a process sensitivity list.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry about that, I'll remove that sentence.